# How to debug variables / recursive data types in Haskell

Tags: debugging, haskell, recursion, functional-programming

https://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/inf1/fp/exams/exam-2016-paper1-answers.pdf

```
-- 3b
trace :: Command -> State -> [State]
trace Nil s = [s]
trace (com :#: mov) s = t ++ [state mov (last t)]
where t = trace com s
```

I am having troubles to understand section 3b. I try to debug the variables one by one but I always end up with violating the defined data types. The code confuses me and I want to see what the variables contain. How can I do it using Debug.Trace?

https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.12.0.0/Debug-Trace.html

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to see the value of `t` for example, do `traceShowId t` instead (assuming `State` implements `Show`). Since `Debug.Trace` gives you a `trace` function that conflicts with the `trace` you define here, you might want to import it qualified, too. What have you been trying that gives you type errors?

Comment: I've been programming in Haskell over 10 years. I've never used Debug.Trace/I've never needed it. Haskell is a functional language; it doesn't have destructive assignment to variables; almost certainly tracing its execution will not help you understand. Despite the name `State` there's no overwriting of state to trace in this example. Get the types and definitions of the operators and functions; substitute those into the equations; apply them.

Comment: I've also been programming in Haskell over 10 years and Debug.Trace has saved my ass many times.  There's nothing wrong with it as a debug tool, and tracing has absolutely helped me understand things about Haskell's runtime behavior.

Comment: I can see tracing would be useful with genuinely stateful/monadic code, to look into encapsulated/abstraction-hiding structures. But there's nothing hidden in this example. I think tracing should not be the first thing beginners reach for. @Darth is right to first ask what errors Petr is running into.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like section 3b is teaching ['How Recursion works'](https://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/inf1/fp/lectures/2017/lect04.pdf) Those slides cover only conventional Haskell Lists. What you have with `:#:` is the opposite, sometimes called a `snoc` list. Then a sensible design for `trace` would be to also produce a `snoc` list result. But it doesn't (presumably because the lecturer thinks that by torturing beginners like this, they'll learn something). Haskell List comprehensions only work for Lists, not `snoc`. (Then half the content in those slides is useless for this exercise.) So 3b is teaching you structural inversion via recursion (which is the useful half of the slides).

> violating the defined data types

Variable `t` in the code you give is local to function `trace`, so it seems difficult to access. But its definition

```
t = trace com s
```

is not:

- We know `trace :: Command -> State -> [State]`
- We can see in the equation for `t` that `trace` is applied to two arguments.
- So the type of `t` must be the type of the result of `trace`, that is `[State]`.

Are you not sure what is the type of the arguments to `trace` in the equation for `t`? In particular `com` unpacked from the `Command` argument to `trace` at top level.

- Then we need to understand the type for `:#:`. We have for Question 3

  ```
  data Command =
       Nil
     | Command :#: Move
  ```
- That makes `(:#:)` an infix operator (which is why I've put it in parens).
- Then we can ask GHCi for its type, to make sure.
- Use the `:type` command, make sure to put parens.
- For contrast, also ask for the `:type` of the usual Haskell List `cons`tructor `(:)` -- see the left-right inversion?
- The term to the left of `(:#:)` is of type `Command`.
- Then variable `com` in the equation for `t` must be type `Command`; and that fits what the call to `trace` is expecting.